# Reason for ksh obsoleting -eq

Tags: scripting, shell-script, ksh

The latest version of ksh obsoletes using `-eq` within `[[ ]]` blocks, prefering `(( ))` instead. Why is this? I can't find any documentation on the advantages of `(( ))` over `[[ ]]` anywhere, and I find that syntax considerably more obvious.

For example:

```
#!/bin/ksh
var=1
if [[ $var -eq 1 ]]
then
  echo ALPHA
fi
```

gives

```
[adam@hendrix test]$ ksh -n test.sh
test.sh: warning: line 3: -eq within [[...]] obsolete, use ((...))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do

```
$ ksh -n 'if [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]; then echo hi; fi'
```

you get the message

```
ksh: warning: line 1: -eq within [[...]] obsolete, use ((...))
```

as you've seen. Now try this:

```
$ ksh -n 'if (( 1 -eq 1 )); then echo hi; fi'
ksh:  1 -eq 1 : arithmetic syntax error
```

This works:

```
$ ksh -n 'if (( 1 == 1 )); then echo hi; fi'
```

Remember that the first message is only a warning. You can continue to use that form. I doubt that it will be removed since it would break too many existing scripts. By the way, this is accepted without a warning:

```
$ ksh -n 'if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then echo hi; fi'
```

One of the [main reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2517727/26428#2518274) that double parentheses is preferred is that the comparison operators are the more familiar `<`, `<=`, `==`, etc., (at least when compared to other languages).

Double parentheses also work in Bash and zsh. A related form, arithmetic substition, works in all of them, plus it's specified by POSIX.

```
$ a=$((3 * 4))
```

Korn, Bash and Z can also do it this way:

```
$ (( a = 3 * 4 ))
```

Even though Dash, as an example of a POSIX shell, doesn't support double parentheses comparisons in the form `if (( ... ))`, you can still do them using arithmetic substitution, but the result is the opposite from what you'd expect (this is also true for the others).

```
$ echo $(( 1 == 1 )); (( 1 == 1 )); echo $?    # in Dash, use true instead of the second statement
1
0
$ echo $(( 1 == 2 )); (( 1 == 2 )); echo $?    # in Dash, use false instead of the second statement
0
1
```